# Вопрос по особенностям различных языков.

Tags: pascal, java, c++

Здравствуйте!
Изучая теорию алгоритмических языков программирования вспомнил один свой старый вопрос...
Вот хочу его задать: Почему в языке паскаль переменные задаются в отдельной секции с var? Зачем это сделано, это облегчает парсинг кода или есть другая причина? Аналогично в Java,  почему package должен быть первым в файле? Программистам было лень написать более качественный анализатор кода? Для чего в паскале в конце программы после end ставят точку? Это какая-то хитрость, которая здорово упростила жизнь создателям компиляторов?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в языке паскаль переменные задаются в отдельной секции с var?

думаю, это к Вирту вопрос. Он так решил. Как по мне - так это удобно для компилятора - он заведомо знает, сколько памяти нужно выделить для каждой функции-процедуры. В случае с/с++ компилятор либо делает плавающий размер стека для каждой функции, либо нужно делать двойной проход. Думаю, это влияние других, более ранних, языков - алгола, разных версий ассемблера.

> Аналогично в Java, почему package должен быть первым в файле?

а представьте, что это не так. Значит у компилятора либо должен быть способ узнать имя пакета другим способом (например, по имени каталога), но тогда зачем писать package.

Иногда программисты добавляют синтаксический сахар. package - один с таких примеров. Для компилятора он не сильно нужен, но для обычного программиста - помогает - это такие опорные якори. С другой стороны, когда компилятор все парсит, он может использовать синтаксический сахар, что бы понимать общий ход программы и более точно выдавать сообщения об ошибках.